# Tagging: Matthew/Mark/Luke/John

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[Nathaniel's question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4648/should-we-try-to-give-questions-at-least-one-reasonably-popular-tag) has got me in a tag maintenance mood.  :)

One thing I noticed is that the tags for the gospel writers are inconsistent.  We current have:

- [matthew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matthew) (unlabeled, but presumably for the person)
- [gospel-of-matthew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel-of-matthew)
- [gospel-of-mark](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel-of-mark)
- [luke](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luke) (explicitly for the person)
- [gospel-of-luke](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel-of-luke)
- [john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john) (unlabeled, barely used)
- [apostle-john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apostle-john)
- [john-apostle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-apostle)
- [gospel-of-john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel-of-john)

I would like to make the usage consistent, how should this be done?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your answer for the most part, but it's basically the status quo anyway. Some questions were just mistagged, and I've retagged the [john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john) and [apostle-john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apostle-john) questions to [john-apostle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-apostle), since he's the one they were about. I've also submitted a tag wiki to make [matthew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matthew)'s scope explicit.

Here's where I have minor disagreements with your answer:

[john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john) should be blacklisted, since it's ambiguous: questions should use [john-apostle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-apostle) for the gospel writer, or [john-the-baptist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-the-baptist) for the other major John.

For the most part, the convention is that the Bible book "Foo" will be tagged as `foo`, and sometimes given synonyms `foo-book` and `book-of-foo`. So [jude](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jude) fits the convention. The only tags about books of the Bible that don't fit that convention are [book-of-james](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-james) (3 questions) and [book-of-judges](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-judges) (6 questions) and the four gospels. I don't think those exceptions are worth our time to "fix" either, but if you want to fix the James and Judges questions, have at it.

Comment: Well, yes my intent was the add a description for [tag:matthew] and retag the poorly tagged questions.  I know there was not a huge number of them, but I didn't want to just act due to my inexperience...  You are correct that we only disagree on a couple (minor) points.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that [matthew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matthew), [mark](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mark) (if the need ever arises), [luke](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luke), and [john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john) should be the tags for the gospel writers.  The tags [apostle-john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apostle-john) and [john-apostle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-apostle) should thus be made synonyms of [john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john).  Questions that are not about the person should be removed from [matthew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matthew) and [john](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john).

There are two other NT books this could apply to, James and Jude.  We currently have [book-of-james](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-james) and [jude](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jude).  For consistency, I feel [jude](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jude) should be renamed [book-of-jude](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-jude).

Comment: Having tags that are specific as in [tag:gospel of john] _and_ ones that less obvious as in [tag:john] will inevitably leave people feeling the need to use both tags. Only by making both the author and book tags sufficiently specific will you cut down on the cross talk and actually get some signal out of the noise.